# Entering emoji fails in django + mysql even with utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, django, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to insert an emoji into my `title` column in my django + MySQL app.

I edited the database directly with PhpMyAdmin. I changed the charset of the column to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and manually inserted an emoji in the table.

This is the table structure:
[image]

And this is the table row with an emoji:
[image]

But when I open this object in the django admin, the emoji is missing:

[image]

And if I try to enter the emoji and save, I get this exception:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\\\xF0\\\\x9F\\\\x92\\\\xA9' for column 'title' at row 1")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of python are you using? And what is the character set of the actual database column?

Comment: The column's charset is already `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. 
I found the answer, I needed to set `'charset': 'utf8mb4'` as an option for the database in django settings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's missing is the `charset` option for the mysql database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            ...
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    }
}
```